# Blank screen after successful install: switching to nouveau from EFI VGA

Tags: debian, installation, nvidia-graphics-card

I successfully installed Debian testing using daily builds with firmware.
The installation is on a dedicated drive. The boot mode is UEFI.

My system is:

- Gigabyte Z690I AORUS Ultra DDR4
- Intel Core-i7-12700KF
- GeForce RTX 3050 OC edition 8GB

When I try to boot into Debian I get a black screen. I tried disabling the graphical desktop, as per [Graphical desktop doesn't work](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=142974), but still get a black screen.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

**Update:**

I removed `quiet` in the `linux` command (after pressing `e` in GRUB menu) and booted. The last message I saw before the screen went black is this.

```
fb0: switching to nouveau from EFI VGA
```

**Update 2:**

I added `nomodeset` parameter and booted. Now I am able to see the UI (with a horrible resolution). Now I'm trying to resolve driver issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was with the absense of proper Nvidia driver. The `nomodeset` kernel param helped to login using UI, and then I had to install actual video driver.

1. The GeForce RTX 3050 driver is available here: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/187162/en-us
   (it's the latest version when I'm answering this question, so when you're reading this it's better to check on their website for newer version of the driver)
2. Before running the installer, get the prerequisites.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   sudo apt-get install libglvnd-dev
   sudo apt-get install pkg-config
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-amd64
   ```
3. Add permission to driver installer `sudo chmod +x ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-....run` and then run it with `sudo`.
4. Blacklist Nvidia nouveau driver.

   ```
    sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
    sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
   ```
5. Regenerate initramfs.

   ```
    sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
6. Reboot (no need to use `nomodeset` after this).

Links that I used to get info:

- https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers
- https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-linux
- https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux